# Repository Pattern for Entity Framework and Children Objects

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an application with the following layers:

Specific WebAPI Controller -> Generic WebAPI Controller Parent Class -> Generic Repository Class -> Entity Framework -> Database

The problem I'm getting is that when I try to retrieve an object with related objects, for instance, BlogPost, with Category and User, the latter two are being returned null. I have the proper relationships defined at the Model (which EF can infer from) as well as foreign key relationships in the database.

I figured this is because my generic repository does a Get only for the main class, and does not include the others.

I know I can get the others if I put in "Include", but how can I do this with generic layers? If I override my methods, that will probably mean that I won't be using the generic methods for majority of my implementation.

Is there another way to tell EF to retrieve the child objects without having to resort to Get overrides?

Comment: Do you have lazy loading enabled?

Comment: You're right. It's turned on by default. If I set it to explicit loading by turning it off, is there a way to limit it to just one level? Both Category and User have collections of BlogPost and I'd like to prevent it from getting all of them. Or is the suggestion to enable passing an Expression across the layers to be used in a LoadProperty method?

Comment: I think this blogpost describes exactly what you are looking for: [Passing Include statements into a Repository](http://www.appetere.com/Blogs/SteveM/May-2012/Passing-Include-statements-into-a-Repository)

Comment: It looks like you are trying to develop CRUD service for entities - that already exists and it is called WCF Data Services.

Comment: @JurajSuchár Thanks. That may be what I need! Please post an answer so that I can choose it.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka Not quite. This is just a starting point. I also would like to do it using WebAPI instead of WCF for simplification, because these will be called via Javascript.

Comment: I've posted though it is "barely more than a link to an external site" ie. violation of answer rules.

Comment: This is actually a pretty good example of why repository classes are overrated and incorrectly regarded as a must-have or a holy grail.